# Extract elements from JSON according to ul li click

Tags: php, jquery, json

In an ajax call, i need to obtain, as a response, the value of a parameter of a JSON object, but i don't understand how to do it.

If this is my PHP file in which i reproduce the JSON structure

```
echo " { ";
echo '"general" : {';
echo '"obj" : [
    {"name" : "Primo", "description" : "Descrizione associata alla prima voce"},
    {"name" : "Secondo", "description" : "Descrizione associata alla seconda voce"},
    {"name" : "Terzo", "description" : "Descrizione associata alla terza voce"}
]}}';
```

And this is my HTML file

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#name li').click(function() {
        var name = $(this).text();
        url = "example.php?name=" + name;
        $.getJSON(url,
            function(json) {
                //for (i = 0; i < json.general.obj.length; i++) {
                //output = "<tr>";
                output = "<td>" + json.general.obj[0].name + "</td>";
                output += "<td>" + json.general.obj[0].description + "</td>";
                //output += "</tr><br/>";

                console.log(output);

                $("#response").append(output);
                //}
            });
        }); 
    });
```

```html
<ul id="name">
    <li data-id="1">Primo</li>
    <li data-id="2">Secondo</li>
    <li data-id="3">Terzo</li>
</ul>   

<div id="response">
    <!--Data goes here-->
</div>
```

Which is the right way to go? Where do i need to place the `$_REQUEST['name']` variable to receive back as a response the desired "Description" value?

I'm stuck there

Comment: Construct a php array on a server side and call [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `data-id` to retrieve the specific item of the array by its index, something like this:

```
$('#name li').click(function() {
    var name = $(this).text();
    var index = $(this).data('id') -1;
    var url = "example.php?name=" + name;

    $.getJSON(url, function(json) {
        output = "<p>" + json.general.obj[index].name + "</p>";
        output += "<p>" + json.general.obj[index].description + "</p>";
        $("#response").append(output);
    }); 
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uktcLudr/)

Note that I changed `td` in the `output` to `p` as `td` elements are only valid within tables.

Also, if you only want the data of the last clicked element to be visible (instead of appending a new set each time) you can use:

```
$("#response").html(output);
```

Comment: Thanks very much, sorry one question: in the list, what does the -1 mean?

Comment: The -1 is there because your ids start at 1, yet array indexes are zero based, so start at 0.